# WCF Data Service: Bad Request - Error in query syntax

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have WCF Data Service application. The back-end database is Ingress and it uses nHibernate.

I am trying to fetch and update records from one of the tables. Its structure is given here under:

[image]

First three highlighted columns make primary key.

In my client application I am querying the data like below:

```
private void LoadItemDetails(string itemCode, int commentDate)
{
    using(var dc = new MyDataContext(new Uri("http://myservice.myserver.com/Dev/com.OData/IngressData.svc")))
    {
        var itemDetails = dc
            .ItemLineDetails
            .Where(d => d.ItemCode.Equals(itemCode) &&
                        ld.CommentDate == commentDate);

        ObsItemLineDetails = new ObservableCollection<ItemLineDets>();
    }
}
```

Then I update and save the data as shown below:

```
private void SaveItemDetails()
{
    using(var dc = new MyDataContext(new Uri("http://myservice.myserver.com/Dev/com.OData/IngressData.svc")))
    {
        foreach(var itemLine in ObsItemLineDetails )
        {
            var today = DateTime.Today.AddSeconds(-1);
            var newCommentDate = (Int32)(today.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1,0,0,0))).TotalSeconds;

            var itemDetail = dc.ItemLineDetails.Where(d => d.ItemCode.Equals(itemLine.ItemCode) && 
                d.LineId == itemLine.LineId && 
                d.SearchDate == itemLine.SearchDate).FirstOrDefault();
            if (itemDetail != null)
            {
                itemDetail.CommentDate = newCommentDate;
                itemDetail.Comments = GetAutoComment();
                dc.UpdateObject(itemDetail);                    
            }
        }                     
        dc.SaveChanges();
    } 
}
```

It raises an exception on the last line when `SaveChanges` is being called. Following is the IIS server log entry.

```
15:52:42.7823 Trace 20 com.OData.DataServiceBase`1 Received: http://myservice.myserver.com/Dev/com.OData/IngressData.svc/ItemLineDetails(ItemCode='001/152/0101',LineId=3,SearchDate=11070945856)
15:52:42.7823 Error 20 com.OData.DataServiceBase`1 Bad Request - Error in query syntax.
at System.Data.Services.RequestUriProcessor.ParsePath(Uri absoluteRequestUri, IDataService service)
at System.Data.Services.RequestUriProcessor.ProcessRequestUri(Uri absoluteRequestUri, IDataService service, Boolean internalQuery)
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()    at System.Data.Services.RequestUriProcessor.ParsePath(Uri absoluteRequestUri, IDataService service)
at System.Data.Services.RequestUriProcessor.ProcessRequestUri(Uri absoluteRequestUri, IDataService service, Boolean internalQuery)
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()
```

I think its probably the forward slashes in my ITEM_CODE field causing this problem.

If that's the case, is there any workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

try to add using on DataContext in the function instead of a global context object
like below

```
private void SaveItemDetails()
{

using(context dc = new context())
{
    foreach(var itemLine in ObsItemLineDetails )
        {
            var today = DateTime.Today.AddSeconds(-1);
            var newCommentDate = (Int32)(today.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1,0,0,0))).TotalSeconds;

            var itemDetail = dc.ItemLineDetails.Where(d => d.ItemCode.Equals(itemLine.ItemCode) && 
                d.LineId == itemLine.LineId && 
                d.SearchDate == itemLine.SearchDate).FirstOrDefault();
            if (itemDetail != null)
            {
                itemDetail.CommentDate = newCommentDate;
                itemDetail.Comments = GetAutoComment();
                dc.UpdateObject(itemDetail);                    
            }
        }                     
        dc.SaveChanges(); 
}
}
```

Comment: DataContext is initialized locally. I missed those lines in my question unfortunately. See my updated question please.